# How to easily switch between dev and prod environments

Tags: proxy, dns, development-environment, production-environment, hosts-file

What is the best way to get dev and test browsers to resolve our production domain name to dev and test environments?  Say our production domain is widgets.com.  In the past, we've used internal DNS for devwidgets.com, testwidgets.com, demowidgets.com, etc.  But this is proving to be big pain.  Seems better to have a host file or proxy server setup so each client can choose to resolve widgets.com to each pre-prod environment.  Ideas?  How have others solved this problem?

Comment: I should mention where we run out of steam with the DNS approach: We maintain several websites for different lines of business (about 6) across 5 environments.  We also have some SAML SSO servers at sso.widgets.com that have to have the same domain name for cookies.

Comment: If you can't/won't use any DNS based solutions, altering the hosts file might work, but it will be an even bigger pain to manage that. You only need to redirect dev.widgets.com to a development server and you can configure that any way you want, including having johndoe.dev.widgets.com for every developer and test.dev.widgets.com for your test environment. Your production server will stay clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can run different versions on different ports (easiest for internal and external setup) or on different cnames (for external setup):

```
dev.widgets.com:81
dev.widgets.com:82
...

dev1.widgets.com
dev2.widgets.com
...
```

This means that the different environments can be configured centrally through the web server rather than having to manage lots of different host files.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved it by using internal dns, like you said. Each developer has his own environment, so I can goto www.ordomain.com.branch2.environment10, where environment10 is my specific environment, and branch2 refers to a specific checkout, in case I got multiple checkouts because I'm working on different projects simultaniously. Just the different environment may suffice for you.

In another situation I've configured a different cname, using dev.widgets.com for remotely getting to my development environment. Disadvantage is that anyone can reach it, so you should password protect it, or use an IP filter.

I wouldn't recomment using hosts files. This is hard to maintain, and you can't reach the live environment from your development pc.